# Getting text area using getBBox()

Tags: d3.js

```
var text = vis.selectAll("text")
    .data(words, function(d) { return d.text.toLowerCase(); });
    text.enter().append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
               return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")"})
    .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })


    var bbox = text.node().getBBox();
```

How do I use getBBox() to get the text area of each text?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best approach here depends on what you're trying to do. Most d3 callback functions will supply the current DOM element as `this`, so this should work:

```
text.each(function() {
    console.log(this.getBBox());
});
```

Beyond that, the question is the context in which you need to use that number. For example, to get the sum of the text widths, you could do:

```
var textWidth = 0;
text.each(function() {
    textWidth += this.getBBox().width;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. this answer helped me find more information on stackoverflow and I'm using text.each(function(d,i)) to get all the information I need. Saved me hours of googling :)

Answer (score 11):

You can also do this synchronously on an element by using node():

```
console.log(text.node().getBBox());
```

Comment: That's much more intuitive than using `each()`