# D3 - Problems centering labels on a SVG made in D3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I can't quite understand how to center the labels on the left of my d3 graph. I have seen that the solution is text-anchor: middle however this isn't working in my case and I'm not too sure why.

This is the D3 Javascript that is building the SVG:

```
function buildSvg(data) {
    var margin = {
            top: 50,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 10,
            left: 150
        },
        width = $('.figure').width() - (margin.left + margin.right),
        height = 50 * data.length;

    var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0.3);

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(['#9ADF2B', '#ef473a', '#ECECEC']);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient('left');

    var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('class', 'd3-plot')
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + 0 + ')');

    color.domain(['Correct', 'Incorrect', 'To complete']);

    data.forEach(function (d) {
        // Creates the percentages
        d['Correct'] = +d[1] * 100 / d.N;
        d['Incorrect'] = +d[2] * 100 / d.N;
        d['To complete'] = +d[3] * 100 / d.N;

        // Changes the starting point.
        var x0 = 0;
        var idx = 0;

        d.boxes = color.domain().map(
            function (name) {
                return {
                    name: name,
                    x0: x0,
                    x1: x0 += +d[name],
                    N: +d.N,
                    n: +d[idx += 1]
                };
            }
        );
    });

    var min_val = d3.min(data, function (d) {
        return d.boxes['0'].x0;
    });

    var max_val = d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.boxes['2'].x1;
    });

    x.domain([min_val, max_val]).nice();
    y.domain(data.map(function (d) {
        return d.Question;
    }));

    svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxis);

    var vakken = svg.selectAll('.question')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('transform', function (d) {
        return 'translate(10,' + y(d.Question) + ')';
    });

    var bars = vakken.selectAll('rect')
    .data(function (d) {
        return d.boxes;
    })
    .enter().append('g').attr('class', 'subbar');

    bars.append('rect')
    .attr('height', y.rangeBand())
    .attr('x', function (d) {
        return x(d.x0);
    })
    .attr('width', function (d) {
        return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0);
    })
    .style('fill', function (d) {
        return color(d.name);
    });

    bars.append('text')
    .attr('x', function (d) {
        return x(d.x0);
    })
    .attr('y', y.rangeBand() / 2)
    .attr('dy', '0.5em')
    .attr('dx', '0.5em')
    .style('font', '10px sans-serif')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.n !== 0 && (d.x1 - d.x0) > 3 ? d.n : '';
    });

    vakken.insert('rect', ':first-child')
    .attr('height', y.rangeBand())
    .attr('x', '1')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('fill-opacity', '0.5')
    .style('fill', '#F5F5F5')
    // If we remove the d parameter it will break the code as it will return as undefined otherwise
    .attr('class', function (d, index) {
        return index % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'uneven';
    });

    // This controls the Axis line.
    svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis axis-line')
    .append('line')
    .attr('x1', x(20))
    .attr('x2', x(20))
    .attr('y2', height);

    d3.selectAll('.axis path')
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('stroke', '#000')
    .style('shape-rendering', 'crispEdges');

    d3.selectAll('.axis line')
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('stroke', '#000')
    .style('shape-rendering', 'crispEdges');

}
```

Below is a jsFiddle of the SVG: 
https://jsfiddle.net/bguLnktk/

This is what I would like the user labels to  look like if possible
[image]

Comment: Can you post the fiddle with the code, instead of with the SVG? BTW, when you say "left", do you want the labels ("User 1" etc) to show up after the gray bar?

Comment: But it is left aligned right now... are you talking about "user 1, "user 2" etc?

Comment: Ignore the position of where the user 1 etc are... they are in the right position... All I'm trying to do is align the text to the left inside its parent in the same position it is atm. So the text is touching the left hand side of the svg and not touching the start of the bar chart

Comment: What text are you trying to align ?

Comment: Alright gang.. I've added a screenshot of how I would like the labels to look. You can see the difference from the fiddle I've added to the question!

Comment: You will have to loop through and translate accordingly.

Comment: I did think that however, what would you do to make it responsive

Comment: just put it in a function and call it when resizing

Comment: How do you create this by the way ? You only have the html at the moment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113512/discussion-between-max-lynn-and-thatoneguy).

Comment: Its created by the javascript above using the D3 lib.

Comment: ok so could you put together a fiddle of your D3 code instead ?

Answer (score 2):

Your problems is the y-axis:

[image]

You has two options.
Option A. Move your axis:

[image]

Option B. Add trail spaces on text ( )

[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: Your right.. I just need to figure out how to change the text-anchor to middle instead of end

Comment: To make this responsive I have to find out the parents width and then half it.. Your almost there. I'm still playing around with it and realised as its a svg child element i have to use a function called getBbox

Comment: Yes. Sorry I didn't mention it before, that would be the 3rd option. You can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922862/getting-text-area-using-getbbox